# What do you call a brief version of your CV?

Tags: word-request

In my language we have two different words for the list of qualifications that you'd include with a job application – on the one hand *CV*, and on the other hand *meritförteckning*. The difference between them is that whereas a *CV* would typically include a brief descriptive or explanatory comment on each entry in the list, the *meritförteckning* would only list qualifications with no further comment.

Now I'm wondering whether English makes the same kind of distinction, and, if so, what the word/phrase corresponding to *meritförteckning* is.

Answer (score 1):

[Précis](https://wikidiff.com/resume/precis) is often used for a short curriculum vitae (CV), aka résumé. However, the term *précis* has the general meaning of an abstract, or "executive summary".

[BTW, the use of diacritics in *résumé* or *précis* can be debated, but I prefer their use in *résumé* to distinguish from the verb meaning, "restart", which is pronounced differently. And some prefer use of a [diaeresis](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis) in *naïve* and *coöperate*... *Chacun à son goût,* and avoid port wine and cheese.]

Comment: Thank you! Question is, though, whether these refer generally to a CV that doesn't go into much detail, so that they can be used for any brief CV, or whether they can **only** be used about a list of qualifications without any kind of elaboration on the various entries? When I look them up in e.g., Cambridge dictionaries, it seems that they have a rather vague meaning of 'summary', rather than specifically a list of qualifications without any further comments?

Comment: (also, I like your sense of humour :)))